# How do I use the value of UITextField in another class?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in TableViewCell, but I want to use the value a user types into the UITextField in TableViewController. There's an IBOutlet to the UITextField in TableViewCell:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
```

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Set your table view controller to be the `UITextField` `delegate`

Comment: What do I do after that to use it in TableViewController?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that the outlet is in TableViewCell (which is the right way of doing it). When `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called you will want to set `cell.username.delegate = self`. This way any time the text field is updated, it will call the delegate method you will implement in the table view controller.

Comment: I did that, but it says: Property 'username' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'.

Comment: @user3398659, are you using a custom cell subclass? If so, are you returning a cell of that type from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, at `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, I have                     `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UsernameTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: Your cell needs to be typed to your custom class, not UITableViewCell -- MyCustomClass *cell = ...

Comment: @rdelmar I did that, and it seemed to work, but when I click submit, I get this error-  Error: username missing (Code: 200, Version: 1.2.15)

Comment: @user3398659, Is the "username" in that error the same as your IBOutlet username? I've not seen an error like that for an IBOutlet. It looks like something from a server download.

Comment: @rdelmar It's from parse. The `cell.username.text` is empty. It's not showing what the user types into the text field.

Comment: @user3398659, That's probably a new question then, unless cell.username is also null.

Comment: @rdelmar It doesn't say (null) it just doesn't have a value.

Comment: @user3398659, what do you mean by that? If you log cell.username, what does it give you?

Comment: @rdelmar When I log `cell.username.text`, it gives me nothing. When I log `cell.username`, it says `text = ''` or rather `Cell <UITextField: 0x9ce6650; frame = (0 0; 320 74); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9cc7e00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x9cde170>>`.